# How to set up base_url with HTTPS without bootstrap.inc error on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, base-url

I set up an SSL security to my domain name, I'm using drupal 7.54, at first the CSS was gone since I didn't configure the $base_url, so I did like this :

```
$base_url = 'https://www.example.com'
```

But the problem is that I couldn't login, so I changed it and tried with :

```
$base_url = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Still no success, can't login... So I found a post who recommend doing it like this :

```
$base_url = '//www.example.com'
```

It work I can finally login and the CSS is here, but now I get this error :

> bootstrap.inc : Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal_settings_initialize()

How can I resolve this ? What's the right method to set up $base_url and making everything work without any errors ?

Comment: $base_url needs to be a 'full' URL

Comment: Also check this once http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115791/base-url-for-both-http-and-https

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave just tried everything in it, still getting access denied, when I try to login